# Getting a weird result for ISO Date in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, sum, dayofweek, isodate

I have a table task_details. I need to select its **weekly date** from this table. I have used **ISO Year** & **ISO Week** to extract the weekly dates from this table as I want to extract its week number as 53 if its Dec,2015 then on the days 28 Dec,29 Dec,30 Dec,31 Dec and 1 Jan '16,2 Jan '16 since it should not separate to two different weeks for these sort of dates.
 The query I have used for **ISO Year** & **ISO Week** is given below.

```
select
    name, id,
    to_date(week || ' ' || yr, 'IW IYYY') week_date,
    sum(worked_hours) worked_hours_per_week,
    week, yr
from (
    select
        name, id,
        newdate, hours worked_hours,
        to_number(to_char(newdate, 'IW'), '99') week,
        extract( year from newdate) yr
    from task_details t
) sub
where worked_hours > 0 
group by name, id, to_date(week || ' ' || yr, 'IW IYYY'), week, yr 
order by yr, week
```

It is working fine for the weeks but then I am getting this weird result for one date for a record in the table.
 The table doesn't have the data for the year 2017.Also, the **yr** column is showing 2016 which is as desired but then the **newdate** column and **week** column is giving weird result. Why is this happening? How do I fix this ?

Here is the SQL fiddle for it :http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53abf/1

Comment: Very creative format. You might be interested in this little helper page: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. While updating the format, remember to include your version of Postgres and a proper table definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mix `week` with `year` in the extract function as `year` is for the Gregorian calendar rather than the special ISO calendar.

See [section 9.9.1 and comments about week](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

`to_number(to_char(newdate, 'IW'), '99')` is effectively `extract(week from newdate)`

Changing the `yr` column to be `extract(isoyear from newdate)` solves your problem.

[Adjusted SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/53abf/3)

Answer (score 1):

[@gwaigh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35376867/939860) already cleared up your confusion of Gregorian and ISO year.

However, your query would be simpler and faster with [**`date_trunc()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to get the first day of each week:

```
SELECT name, id
     , date_trunc('week', newdate)::date AS week_date
     , extract(week FROM newdate)::int       AS week
     , extract(isoyear from newdate)::int    AS isoyr  -- must be ISO year to match
     , sum(hours)                            AS worked_hours_per_week
FROM   task_details
WHERE  hours > 0
GROUP  BY name, id, week_date, week, yr
ORDER  BY week_date;
```

Also simplified your query.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c7463/5)

Either way, if you work with `timestamptz` then year, week or date depend on your current timezone setting. (It can be a different year, depending on where you are right now.)